# R customize error message when string contains unrecognized escape

Tags: r, regex

I would like to give a more informative error message when users of my R functions supply a string with an unrecognized escape

```
my_string <- "sql\sql"
# Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""sql\s"
```

Something like this would be ideal.

```
my_string <- "sql\sql"
# Error: my_string contains an unrecognized escape. Try sql\\sql with double backslashes instead.
```

I have tried an if statement that looks for single backslashes

```
if (stringr::str_detect("sql\sql", "\")) stop("my error message")
```

but I get the same error.

Almost all of my users are Windows users running R 3.3 and up.

Comment: You need to escape `my_string <- "sql\\sql"`  `cat(my_string)#
sql\sql`

Comment: @MrFlick I like your response about having users write valid code using double backslashes where appropriate. I would accept this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code execution in R happens in two phases. First, R takes the raw string you enter and parses that into commands that can be run; then, R actually runs those commands. The parsing step makes sure what you've written actually makes sense as code. If it doesn't make any sense, then R can't even turn it into anything it can attempt to run.

The error message you are getting about the unrecognized escape sequence is happening at the parsing stage. That means R isn't really even attempting to execute the command, it just straight up can't understand what you are saying. There is no way to catch in error like this in code because there's no user code that's running at that point.

So if you are counting on your users writing code like `my_string <- "something"`, then they need to write valid code. They can't change how strings are encoded or what the assignment operator looks like or how variables can be named. They also can't type `!my_string! <=== %something%` because R can't parse that either. R can't parse `my_string <- "sql\sql"` but it can parse `my_string <- "sql\\sql"` (slashes much be escaped in string literals). If they are not savy users, you might want to consider providing an alternative interface that can sanitize user input before trying to run it as code. Maybe make a shiny front end or have users pass arguments to your scripts via command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're capturing your user input correctly, for a string input of`\`, R will store that in `my_string` as `\\`.

```
readline()
\
[1] "\\"

readline()
sql\sql
[1] "sql\\sql"
```

That means internally in R:

```
my_string <- "sql\\sql"
```

However

```
cat(my_string)

sql\sql
```

To check the input, you need to escape each escape, because you're looking for `\\`

```
stringr::str_detect(my_string, "\\\\")
```

Which returns `TRUE` if the input string is `sql\sql`. So the full line is:

```
if (stringr::str_detect("sql\\sql", "\\\\")) stop("my error message")
```