# How to process latex commands in R?

Tags: r, escaping, latex, backslash

I work with knitr() and I wish to transform inline Latex commands like "\label" and "\ref", depending on the output target (Latex or HTML).

In order to do that, I need to (programmatically) generate valid R strings that correctly represent the backslash: for example "\label" should become "\\label". The  goal would be to replace all backslashes in a text fragment with double-backslashes.

but it seems that I cannot even read these strings, let alone process them: if I define:

```
okstr <- function(str) "do something"
```

then when I call

```
okstr("\label")
```

I directly get an error "unrecognized escape sequence"
(of course, as \l is faultly)

So my question is : does anybody know a way to read strings (in R), without using the escaping mechanism ?

Yes, I know I could do it manually, but that's the point: I need to do it programmatically. 
There are many questions that are close to this one, and I have spent some time browsing, but I have found none that yields a workable solution for this.

Best regards.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085922/r-customize-error-message-when-string-contains-unrecognized-escape/52102206#52102206

Answer (score 1):

*Inside R code*, you need to adhere to R’s syntactic conventions. And since `\` in strings is used as an escape character, it needs to form a valid escape sequence (and `\l` isn’t a valid escape sequence in R).

There is simply no way around this.

But if you are reading the string from elsewhere, e.g. using `readLines`, `scan` or any of the other file reading functions, you are already getting the correct string, and no handling is necessary.

Alternatively, if you absolutely want to write LaTeX-like commands in literal strings inside R, just use a different character for `\`; for instance, `+`. Just make sure that your function correctly handles it everywhere, and that you keep a way of getting a literal `+` back. Here’s a suggestion:

```
okstr("+label{1 ++ 2}")
```

The implementation of `okstr` then needs to replace single `+` by `\`, and double `++` by `+` (making the above result in `\label{1 + 2}`). But consider in which order this needs to happen, and how you’d like to treat more complex cases; for instance, what should the following yield: `okstr("1 +++label")`?